# Помогите разобраться с запятой

Tags: пунктуация

Подскажите, пожалуйста, правильно ли стоит запятая?

> Благодаря встроенной розетке, шнур утюга стал гораздо длиннее.

Comment: А зачем она тут?

Comment: Ну я и спрашиваю, нужна или нет?

Comment: Я и спрашиваю знающих людей, нужна или нет?

Comment: А зачем ставите, если не знаете?

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что домашние задания тут не делают.

Comment: 1)  ЭТО ГРМОТНЫЙ ВОПРОС?  Стал ли длиннее шнур утюга?  Как шнур может стать длиннее благодаря встроенной розетке?  Вообще говоря, удлинить любой шнур можно с помощью переходника, вот таким переходником и является розетка на гладильной доске, позволяющая увеличить расстояние межу розеткой в стене и утюгом. Поэтому  и пишут в рекламе:  "Шнур утюга стал еще длиннее! Подключите утюг к розетке, расположенной на нижней поверхности доски, и наслаждайтесь максимальной свободой действий благодаря длине шнура".

Comment: Таким образом, семантика заданного предложения ясна, ну а форму можно исправить с помощью кавычек: Благодаря встроенной розетке, шнур утюга стал гораздо "длиннее". 2) О ДОМАШНЕМ ЗАДАНИИ. Я тоже не люблю делать домашние задания, но я не понимаю, почему это домашнее задние. В предложении стоит одна запятая (достаточно спорная), и автор интересуется правомерностью ее постатновки. Вопрос сформулирован вежливо и корректно.

Answer (score 1):

Запятая факультативна.Обычно обособляются предлоги распространенные обороты, то есть содержат существительное с зависимыми словами:

Ср: **Благодаря отличной погоде и особенно праздничному дню,** улица сельца Марьинского снова оживилась (Григорович).

**Благодаря этим наводящим вопросам**, Дунька рассказала по порядку всё происшествие. Д. Мамин-Сибиряк, Озорник.

Comment: Благодаря Сержу встроенная розетка факультативно войдет в анналы.

Comment: А вы себе не изменяете, профессор behemothus!

Comment: Я правилам не изменяю, г. Серж. А вот Вы бежите отвечать на всякий бесполезный вопрос - не дай бог кто раньше ответит. Даже не задумались, какой бред написан. Ну как шнур может стать длиннее ***благодаря встроенной розетке?***

Comment: А вы стремитесь любой вопрос заблокировать,лишь бы очки заработать! Это мало, так еще грубите, хамите не только участникам форума, но и новичкам! Это ваша натура!

Comment: Не фантазируйте. И не переходите нас личности. За "блокировку" вопроса никто очков не дает, скорее отнять могут. И не любой совсем. Моя претензия к вопросу (а заодно и к вашему ответу)  очевидна.

Answer (score 1):

Благодаря встроенной розетке //шнур утюга стал гораздо длиннее.

**Предлагаю не ставить запятую**, так как в этом нет необходимости. Это типичная конструкция **простого предложения** по семантике, грамматике и интонации.

**Примеры**

Благодаря чуть изогнутой форме стальных колец в браслете //часы прилегают к запястью как вторая кожа. Благодаря работам Л. Эйлера, Ж. Лагранжа и А. Лежандра //теория чисел приобретает характер систематической науки.

**А вот примеры обособленных обстоятельств:**

**Благодаря этой серьёзной лингвистической и литературоведческой работе**, впервые стало возможным говорить о рождении жанра танка. **Благодаря своему дарованию**, они сразу же выходят за рамки собственно философии, а их идеи имеют несравнимо более широкое влияние.

Здесь  обстоятельство обозначает **обособленную (отдельную!) ситуацию**, которая связана с содержанием основного предложения, но не входит в его состав (таким образом мы имеем **две ситуации**). Соответственно, можно сделать вывод вывод, что при обособлении обстоятельства нужно учитывать распространенность **как самого оборота, так и самодостаточное содержание основной части.**

Comment: Sibylla, а чем отличается, например, мой второй пример, от примера в вопросе?  Хотя обстоятельственные обороты в начале не обособляются, обособление не будет ошибкой. Решение принимает автор.

Comment: Серж, здесь нет речи об ошибке (в большинстве случаев запятую можно ставить или не ставить), просто  решение, которое принимает автор, он как-то для себя объясняет. И на выбор этого решения чаще всего влияет несколько факторов: стиль произведения, предыдущий текст, из которого взято предложение, позиция и распространенность оборота, общая семантика  фрагмента.  В конечном счете мы  решаем, будем ли мы строить сложную конструкцию или включим оборот в простое предложение.

Comment: В художественных произведениях обособление оборота в препозиции встречается чаще  -   подчеркивается  полиситуативность сообщения. В Вашем примере "Дуняша всё и по порядку рассказала" - это  основное содержание, а причину автор решил выделить в самостоятельное сообщение.  Соответственно, при обособлении делается характерная пауза, подчеркивающая двухчастность  предложения.